# Installation Ubuntu through wubi dool boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I have a power edge T620 system with Windows Server 2008 R2 installed.

I'd like to dual boot this and install Ubuntu 14.04 on it

So I created a bootable USB and after I select the

Install Ubuntu or even try Ubuntu without installing option

I get this error message

18042 : no controller found

megasas : IOC init cmd success

megasas : INIT adapter done

I have no idea how to proceed from here.
it's work in safe mode but  I want to install in normal mode
I have anther question what is the difference between normal mode and safe mode
Would be extremely grateful if someone could help me

Comment: What did you use to create the USB?

Answer (score 0):

probably corrupt way of making bootable usb. anyways. that is booting and installing Ubuntu. good, but not WUBI. wubi nowadays is not supported by Ubuntu Makers. so community made better & newer version!

use this

https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki go to the table and click on the thing for wubirelease for 14.04

magic!!